# Hold thread until listener catches an event

Tags: java, listener, spring-transactions

Situation: I have a transactional method, which execute void method,
for example:

```
@Transactional
public void createCall() {
    callManager.makeCall();
}
```

Let's assume that CallManager contains method like this:

```
public void makeCall() {
    Call call = CallFactory.createCall();
    CallListener listener = new CallListener();
    call.addListener(listener);
    call.connect();
}
```

If connect() method doesn't throw exceptions, makeCall() method successfully completes.

Now, in listener we have handlers method, for example:

```
public void callTalking(AnyEvent event) {
    //some logic
}
```

The main question is: is there a beautiful way to hold our transactional method **createCall()** till listener catches event in **callTalking()** without using timeouts?

**EDIT**
Important info, that I'm using gigaspace polling event, which (shortly speak) **takes** object from database after successfull transaction for ever.

Comment: I do not see logic divided into threads, so waiting is not necessary. However, if there are different threads, you can use sync between them (`Object#wait()` and `Object#notify()`)

Comment: The main problem is th next situation. Application placed a call successfully, but operator didn't take a call, and at the same time application crushed and the call lost. But transaction marked as successfull, and there was no rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example logic for synchronization. Keep in mind that if it runs on a thread, it will block forever. In this example, the main thread will block while the thread on which Call works does not process an event.

```
public void makeCall() {
    Object semafor = new Object();
    synchronized (semafor) {
        try {
            CallListener listener = new CallListener() {
                @Override
                public void callTalking(AnyEvent event) {
                    // some logic

                    synchronized (semafor) {
                        semafor.notify();
                    }
                }
            };

            Call call = CallFactory.createCall();
            call.addListener(listener);
            call.connect();

            semafor.wait();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```